# WindowsCommand Line > Edit a specific string (containing an equals sign) from a text file

Tags: command-line, windows-xp, replace

I've spent some time poking around stackoverflow and the net in general looking for a well described answer to this problem.

I have a piece of software that installs itself and reads a .ini file. This .ini is of variable size and variable line numbers. The style of every line is something like the following:

```
setting1=contents
setting2=more,contents
setting3=different type of contents
setting4=youget/theidea
```

I need to search this text file for a few specific lines, let's say it's the following:

```
Username=Tommy
Servername=HAL2000
```

And then replace the values after the equals sign (i.e. change Tommy to Timmy). My problem is that all of the scripting I've found and tried to incorporate either sees the values above as a variable (i.e. username becomes a variable with value "Tommy") or when I go to replace Tommy with timmy, the .ini file ends up replacing EVERY line in the file with Username=Tommy.

I've since deleted both of these scripts and moved on, but the more I think about it the more I want to go back and do this script.

Only rule is that is HAS to be in Windows command line with commands native to XP. No third party programs, no python, no perl, nothing but Windows command line that can be run out of a .bat file.

Comment: *No third party programs* Oh boy, can I use some linux commands like `awk`? http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to be clumsy, but if the number of keys to be replaced is limited, the following might be enough for you:

```
@echo off

set infile=foo.ini
set outfile=newfile.ini

rem create an empty output file
echo. > %outfile%

rem iterate over all properties
for /f " usebackq eol=# tokens=1,2 delims== " %%i in ("%infile%") do (
  call :replace %%i %%j
)

rem terminate batch file
goto :eof

rem sub-program to do the replacing
:replace

  if "%1"=="Username" (
    echo Username=Timmy>>%outfile%
    goto :eof
  )

  if "%1"=="Servername" (
    echo Servername=HAL2001>>%outfile%
    goto :eof
  )
  echo %1=%2>>%outfile%

  rem terminate sub-program
  goto :eof
```

Comment: Clumsy will work perfectly. I'll test this and let you know how it works. The program this is for is for a delightful mess that uses Microsoft Access... Except the records are all stored in an SQL database... and the program converts them from SQL to Access... And still advertises as being SQL based... Not relevant to this, but I think anyone with SQL knowledge knows how awful that is. There are about 2-4 variables to change, so yes - scope is very limited.

Comment: I'm working on trying to correct this myself, since you've given me a lot to work with, but right now the script is only echoing 3 lines from the .ini that have nothing to do with what I want, and it's not changing what I want changed. It's worth explaining further that I don't want to change the value of Username only when it's Tommy. I want to change the value of Username EVERY TIME. Same for Servername, to continue using the example. I want to change Servername to HAL2001 no matter what its value is at the time the script runs. Also it's not saving the changes its making (if any).

Comment: @incongruouserudite To change servername and username *all* the time, just remove the nested if (see my edit). The changes are saved to a different file (that's the `outfile=newfile.ini` part). You cannot overwrite the file you are reading from.

Comment: I kept working at it and realized exactly what you just told me, but on my own. I feel so accomplished ;) The script was working perfectly except I totally didn't pay attention to the fact that it was saving the newfile.ini and not overwriting the other .ini. Either way I got it fixed and figured out. Thanks for the help - I'd up rep you, but I don't have enough rep myself :(

Answer (score 1):

The a_horse_with_no_name solution works perfectly well for your requirements. It can be made a bit less clumsy and more efficient by eliminating the CALLs. The MOVE command is used to overwrite the original file with the new data.

```
@echo off
>"test.ini.new" (
  for /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims==" %%A in ("test.ini") do (
    if %%A==Username (
      echo %%A=Timmy
    ) else if %%A==Servername (
      echo %%A=HAL2001
    ) else echo %%A=%%B
  )
)
move /y "test.ini.new" "test.new"
```

The above assumes every line in the file meets your stated format. But often times an .INI file also has comment lines that do not meet the format that should be preserved. The FOR loop solution can be extended to support that, but it becomes even more complicated, and slower.

You never explicitly stated the order of the lines is important - often times the order of lines in a .INI file is not important. Here is a really simple solution that uses FINDSTR to strip out the existing Username and Servername lines and then appends the new values to the end. All unchanged lines will be preserved, regardless of format. The changed lines always appear at the end.

```
@echo off
>"test.ini.new" (
  findstr /v "^Username= ^Servername=" "test.ini"
  echo Username=Timmy
  echo Servername=HAL2001
)
move /y "test.ini.new" "test.new"
```

Batch is really a poor platform for processing text files. It is often slow and overly complicated. It looks like your file is small, and your requirements are relatively simple. But many seemingly simple requests are a beast to do in pure batch.

JScript is much better for processing text, and it is native to XP and beyond. It has full regex support. I have written a hybrid batch/JScript utility script that can be used to perform search and replace operations on the contents of text files. It is very fast, powerful, and simple to use. A solution to your problem is implemented as:

```
@echo off
type "test.ini" | repl "^Username=.*$" "Username=Timmy" | repl "^Servername=.*$" "Servername=HAL2001" >"test.ini.new"
move /y "test.ini.new" "test.new"
```

or a bit more concisely as:

```
@echo off
type "test.ini" | repl "^(Username=).*$" "$1Timmy" | repl "^(Servername=).*$" "$1=HAL2001" >"test.ini.new"
move /y "test.ini.new" "test.new"
```

Below is the REPL.BAT utility script. Full documentation is embedded within the script. The documentation can also be accessed from the command prompt by typing `REPL /?`. The script should either be in your current directory, or else somewhere in your PATH.

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* Harmless hybrid line that begins a JScript comment

::************ Documentation ***********
:::
:::REPL  Search  Replace  [Options  [SourceVar]]
:::REPL  /?
:::
:::  Performs a global search and replace operation on each line of input from
:::  stdin and prints the result to stdout.
:::
:::  Each parameter may be optionally enclosed by double quotes. The double
:::  quotes are not considered part of the argument. The quotes are required
:::  if the parameter contains a batch token delimiter like space, tab, comma,
:::  semicolon. The quotes should also be used if the argument contains a
:::  batch special character like &, |, etc. so that the special character
:::  does not need to be escaped with ^.
:::
:::  If called with a single argument of /? then prints help documentation
:::  to stdout.
:::
:::  Search  - By default this is a case sensitive JScript (ECMA) regular
:::            expression expressed as a string.
:::
:::            JScript syntax documentation is available at
:::            http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae5bf541(v=vs.80).aspx
:::
:::  Replace - By default this is the string to be used as a replacement for
:::            each found search expression. Full support is provided for
:::            substituion patterns available to the JScript replace method.
:::            A $ literal can be escaped as $$. An empty replacement string
:::            must be represented as "".
:::
:::            Replace substitution pattern syntax is documented at
:::            http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/efy6s3e6(v=vs.80).aspx
:::
:::  Options - An optional string of characters used to alter the behavior
:::            of REPL. The option characters are case insensitive, and may
:::            appear in any order.
:::
:::            I - Makes the search case-insensitive.
:::
:::            L - The Search is treated as a string literal instead of a
:::                regular expression. Also, all $ found in Replace are
:::                treated as $ literals.
:::
:::            E - Search and Replace represent the name of environment
:::                variables that contain the respective values. An undefined
:::                variable is treated as an empty string.
:::
:::            M - Multi-line mode. The entire contents of stdin is read and
:::                processed in one pass instead of line by line. ^ anchors
:::                the beginning of a line and $ anchors the end of a line.
:::
:::            X - Enables extended substitution pattern syntax with support
:::                for the following escape sequences:
:::
:::                \\     -  Backslash
:::                \b     -  Backspace
:::                \f     -  Formfeed
:::                \n     -  Newline
:::                \r     -  Carriage Return
:::                \t     -  Horizontal Tab
:::                \v     -  Vertical Tab
:::                \xnn   -  Ascii (Latin 1) character expressed as 2 hex digits
:::                \unnnn -  Unicode character expressed as 4 hex digits
:::
:::                Escape sequences are supported even when the L option is used.
:::
:::            S - The source is read from an environment variable instead of
:::                from stdin. The name of the source environment variable is
:::                specified in the next argument after the option string.
:::

::************ Batch portion ***********
@echo off
if .%2 equ . (
  if "%~1" equ "/?" (
    findstr "^:::" "%~f0" | cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" "^:::" ""
    exit /b 0
  ) else (
    call :err "Insufficient arguments"
    exit /b 1
  )
)
echo(%~3|findstr /i "[^SMILEX]" >nul && (
  call :err "Invalid option(s)"
  exit /b 1
)
cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" %*
exit /b 0

:err
>&2 echo ERROR: %~1. Use REPL /? to get help.
exit /b

************* JScript portion **********/
var env=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Environment("Process");
var args=WScript.Arguments;
var search=args.Item(0);
var replace=args.Item(1);
var options="g";
if (args.length>2) {
  options+=args.Item(2).toLowerCase();
}
var multi=(options.indexOf("m")>=0);
var srcVar=(options.indexOf("s")>=0);
if (srcVar) {
  options=options.replace(/s/g,"");
}
if (options.indexOf("e")>=0) {
  options=options.replace(/e/g,"");
  search=env(search);
  replace=env(replace);
}
if (options.indexOf("l")>=0) {
  options=options.replace(/l/g,"");
  search=search.replace(/([.^$*+?()[{\\|])/g,"\\$1");
  replace=replace.replace(/\$/g,"$$$$");
}
if (options.indexOf("x")>=0) {
  options=options.replace(/x/g,"");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\\\/g,"\\B");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\b/g,"\b");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\f/g,"\f");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\n/g,"\n");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\r/g,"\r");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\t/g,"\t");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\v/g,"\v");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}|\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}/g,
    function($0,$1,$2){
      return String.fromCharCode(parseInt("0x"+$0.substring(2)));
    }
  );
  replace=replace.replace(/\\B/g,"\\");
}
var search=new RegExp(search,options);

if (srcVar) {
  WScript.Stdout.Write(env(args.Item(3)).replace(search,replace));
} else {
  while (!WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream) {
    if (multi) {
      WScript.Stdout.Write(WScript.StdIn.ReadAll().replace(search,replace));
    } else {
      WScript.Stdout.WriteLine(WScript.StdIn.ReadLine().replace(search,replace));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It may be better to use a tool dedicated to ini files like:
https://github.com/pixelb/crudini